# Python JSON module won't parse my Windows-1252 string

Tags: python, json

I'm getting some JSON data back from a server, and the server say it's Windows-1252. So I try to load it with that encoding but get `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` in response. What am I doing wrong? (I realize that it has something to do with BOM, but that doesn't help me.)

```
import json
my_data = u'\ufeff{"columns":[{"code":"Region","text":"region","type":"d"},{"code":"Tid","text":"\xe5r","type":"t"},{"code":"BE0101E2","text":"Levande f\xf6dda","type":"c"}],"comments":[],"data":[{"key":["0114","2014"],"values":["485"]}]}'

json.loads(my_data, encoding='Windows-1252')
```

Comment: You don't have a CP-1252 string. You have a Unicode string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a **Unicode** object, not a CP-1252 byte stream.

The decode fails because there is a [U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](https://codepoints.net/U+FEFF) character at the start, probably left over from decoding data with a [Byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

The data loads without problems if you remove it:

```
>>> import json
>>> my_data = u'\ufeff{"columns":[{"code":"Region","text":"region","type":"d"},{"code":"Tid","text":"\xe5r","type":"t"},{"code":"BE0101E2","text":"Levande f\xf6dda","type":"c"}],"comments":[],"data":[{"key":["0114","2014"],"values":["485"]}]}'
>>> json.loads(my_data[1:])
{u'data': [{u'values': [u'485'], u'key': [u'0114', u'2014']}], u'comments': [], u'columns': [{u'text': u'region', u'code': u'Region', u'type': u'd'}, {u'text': u'\xe5r', u'code': u'Tid', u'type': u't'}, {u'text': u'Levande f\xf6dda', u'code': u'BE0101E2', u'type': u'c'}]}
```

You could remove it conditionally:

```
if my_data.startswith(u'\ufeff'):
    my_data = my_data[1:]
```

or use a correct codec to decode the data from bytes; if it was UTF-8 encoded you could use `utf-8-sig` to decode and remove the BOM.

`json.loads()` cannot be configured to load `utf-8-sig` data; it'll just treat it as UTF-8 and still trip over the BOM. In that case you can decode manually first.